# 3 races at different levels of technology

Tags: story-identification, magic, technology

In 8th grade I read a sci-fi/fantasy story about a technologically advanced race that is trying to colonize a world already populated by a "primitive" race that believes that the technology of the colonizers is magic. Meanwhile, a third, even-more-evolved race is observing the interactions between the two less-evolved civilizations.  Can't think of the name of it and would love to re-visit if anyone has a clue what I'm remembering...

Comment: Since we do not know how old you are, you being in 8th grade doesn't help us out. Can you give us a time-frame of when you read it or think it was published? Was it in an anthology book, or just a single author collection? Can you remember the cover? Any other clues would help. It sounds like a good story.

Comment: This may be 'Enchantress From The Stars' by Sylvia Engdahl.

Comment: Enchantress from the Stars was my first thought too.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137223/story-with-multiple-third-planet-races (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Was this maybe [Enchantress from The Stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchantress_from_the_Stars) by Sylvia Engdahl? It's similar to what you're describing.